What does Pythons syntax "in" essentially do?
Say I have an arbitrary container, and an inquiry whether an element is in it, see below.
D = {(1, 2): "whatever"}
if (2, 1) in D:
    print( "Impossible" ) 

What really happens in terms of underlying code? does any specific member function such as find() get called?
Moreover, can I use a customized cmp/hash? say, if I would like to compare only occurrence of each number in the key of tuple as shown in the code snippet, what can I do to achieve it?
D = {(1, 2, 1): "whatever"}
if (2, 1, 1) in D:
    print( "As expected" ) # How to make it happen?

An official Py document will be much appreciated, I assume it's a quite fundamental info but cannot find an official intro anywhere.

Many thanks for quick answer & help, so does that mean there is no way to customize a built-in container, but only to inherit or encapsulate one?

There;s no way to directly customize what any method of any built-in  type does. __contains__() is nothing special in this respect. For example. there's no way to directly change what int.__add__() does either. In CPython, you would need to edit the C source code that implements the method and recompile.

Understood, many thanks for answering again.

Are you saying that you would want (2,1,1) to be equivalent to (1,2,1)? If so, implement __contains__ and compare sorted values therein

This is defined in the language reference section 6.10.2. Membership test operations; in particular:

All built-in sequences and set types support this as well as dictionary, for which in tests whether the dictionary has a given key. For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).
[…] For user-defined classes which define the __contains__() method, x in y returns True if y.__contains__(x) returns a true value, and False otherwise. […]


Under the covers, x in y invokes y.__contains__(x). So the behavior depends entirely on how type(y) implements the special __contains__ method.
>>> class X:
...     def __contains__(self, i):
...         if i == 4:
...             return True
...         elif i < 0:
...             return "hamburger"
...         else:
...             return False
...
>>> 3 in X()
False
>>> 4 in X()
True
>>> -4 in X()
True

That last one might be surprising. It does not return "hamburger", but under the covers another layer applies bool() to what __contains__() does actually return.
>>> bool("hamburger")
True

